# return value from list of key-value pair object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have what I think a pretty simple issue but I'm not able to find the solution.

I'm printing the following object:

```
test = df['metrics']
print(test)

0       [{'values': ['4']}]
1      [{'values': ['23']}]
2      [{'values': ['32']}]
3       [{'values': ['1']}]
4       [{'values': ['2']}]
5       [{'values': ['1']}]
6     [{'values': ['113']}]
7       [{'values': ['1']}]
8       [{'values': ['2']}]
9       [{'values': ['2']}]
10      [{'values': ['1']}]
Name: metrics, dtype: object
```

I'd like to return only the values. I've tried `.values()`, lamba function but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['metrics'] = df['metrics'].explode().map(lambda x: x['values']).explode()
#df['metrics'] = df['metrics'].explode().map(lambda x: x.values()).explode() #not the same
```

or if you only want get postion 0 of the list:

```
df['metrics'].map(lambda x: x[0]['values']).explode()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an empty list and a helper function, then use a for loop to iterate through key, value pairs and append each value to the list. And finally just return the list.

Comment: There are pandas and numpy methods optimized to avoid having to use loops, especially external ones.

Comment: I meant an internal one, but I don't have any experience with pandas honestly, so your answer is probably the better one to use.